# How do I SSH and remove all previous SSH activity history?

Tags: ssh, history

I want to remove any and all activity logs for SSH remotely. How do I get to it?

My account on the remote server doesn't have admin privilege, and as such I just want to remove user to user connection records.

Comment: This sounds suspicious. :)

Comment: @Richard, sure it does, but what sounds more suspicious is deleting everything as opposed to just deleting the current session's data.

Comment: regarding update: not going to happen. If the admin is worth his salt all logs are world-readable but not editable by any one other than the admin (ie. root or sudo permissions required).

Comment: @Rinzwind, nothing is saved in the user directory itself? In the `.ssh` directory or something, for example.

Comment: The commands you issued when you have access will be in your bash history file. That's about all I can think of.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The answer to this lies in [sshd.conf](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/man5/sshd_config.5.html) and `sshd_config` (server) and `ssh_config` (client). Depending on the log level it logs to `/var/log/syslog` (default) and/or `/var/log/auth.log` (loglevel 'verbose' contains ssh login attempts).

If present `/var/log/secure` also contains an access log.

You will need `root`/`sudo` access to edit any of these files: they will be word-readable but not world-editable.

Next to that. Besides the login from the ssh daemon the command `last` also shows (failed) logins from ssh. The information for this command comes from `/var/log/wtmp` (There will be several more I bet).

And there is also the probability the sysadmin installed `auditd` or `logwatch` making it practically impossible to hide activity since they could get a notice based on activity undoing the registration of the ssh activity impossible.

Example of `/var/log/auth.log`:

```
Aug 10 10:10:10 rinzwind sshd[3653]: Invalid user text from {ipadress}
Aug 10 10:10:10 rinzwind sshd[3653]: Excess permission or bad ownership on file /var/log/btmp
Aug 10 10:10:10 rinzwind sshd[3653]: error: Could not get shadow information for NOUSER
Aug 10 10:10:10 rinzwind sshd[3653]: Failed password for invalid user test from {ipadress} port {port} ssh2
Aug 10 10:10:10 rinzwind sshd[3653]: Excess permission or bad ownership on file /var/log/btmp
```

Comment: Updated question.

Comment: By the way, just what kind of data is logged when SSH connection takes place? IP address for sure, but what else?

Comment: No username recorded?

Answer (score 1):

You would want to look at `/var/log/messages` and/or `/var/log/syslog`.